# How expired content handled in Oracle Content Server 11g?

Tags: oracle-ucm

We have a discrepancy in our development and production content servers (11g) in the
way that expired content is automatically handled.
- In dev, the original file is deleted and replaced with a file of the same
name, except with a "~1" appended to the end of the web location. The original
file is no longer available from it's original web location.
- In production, the same process occurs, but the original file is still
accessible via the original web location, which indicates it was not deleted.

It's been a struggle to track down the source of this configuration. Is this an
out-of-the-box feature, or does this have to be configured on it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is the out-of-the-box feature.
By default each content item's revision has meta-field 'Expiration Date' which defines when expiration will occur.

Expired content revisions are marked correspondingly in the database (revisions.dstatus='EXPIRED') thus they will not be accessible in application via search, but can still be found by administrator (Content Management -> Expired Content).

Expired revision files are not deleted from *weblayout*, but renamed instead as *not latest* revisions - marked with ~{number} postfix.
Expired revision files are neither deleted from *vault* nor renamed.

Lets say we have 2 revisions (dID=31026 and dID=31025) of a picture 009139 (dDocName=009139). Both revisions are expired. In this case:

- both revisions are marked as expired in DB:

```
DID                    DDOCNAME                       DSTATUS              
---------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------- 
31026                  UP_009139                      EXPIRED              
31025                  UP_009139                      EXPIRED
```

- both revision files will be renamed in weblayout:

```
\ucm\weblayout\groups\public\@test\documents\multimedia\up_009139~1.gif 
\ucm\weblayout\groups\public\@test\documents\multimedia\up_009139~2.jpg
```

- neither revision 1 nor revision 2 will be renamed/deleted in vault:

```
\ucm\vault\multimedia\@test\31025.gif
\ucm\vault\multimedia\@test\31026.jpg
```

Regarding your issue with prod - make sure you had no further revisions after the expired one (in this case this revision will be, of course, available)